# Ways of reference subsection number from another article?

Tags: cross-referencing, citing, back-referencing

We have subsection 9.5 of article [2].

We can mentioned this subsection by:

```
Please see in \S9.5 of [2]
```

or

```
Please see in \S9.5 of aricle [2]
```

1)Do we have a short way as:

```
Please see in \S9.5[2]
```

2)Can we write inside brackets only a section number without an article number:

```
Please see in article [2] (see \S9.5)
```

Or we have to write an article number also in brackets as:

```
 Please see in article [2] (see \S9.5 of article [2])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not too clear to me but I try to help: The following shows the "normal" ways to mention the section in a citation according to my knowledge. For future reference, please have a look at [this post](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228) and [this post](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407) so that your questions improve in quality.

```
% https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407

\documentclass{article}

% https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
% \usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{key,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item \cite[][Section~9.1]{key}
    \item \parencite[][Section~9.1]{key}  % biblatex manuel, 3.9.1 Standard Commands
    \item \textcite[][Section~9.1]{key} % biblatex manuel, 3.9.2 Style-specific Commands
\end{itemize}


\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

*(Using `\usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex}`)*

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! Soo according your answer it is legal to write: Please see in article [1, §9.1]

Comment: Yes, that's "legal" :)